# Validating made up fields in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, validation

Here's my scenario:
I'm creating a password change page.
the real field that holds the password is User.password

On the password create page, I used 3 made up fields:
$form->input('User.old_passwd');
$form->input('User.new_passwd');
$form->input('User.confirm_new_passwd');

How do I validate them with the rules:

- old password must match User.password
- new_passwd and confirmnew_passwd must
  be equal

Are there better solutions for this? I'm open for suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in authentication component doesn't offer that functionality. I would specify the validation rules for your "made up" fields in the `validate` property of the model and write my own validation methods, for example: `correctPassword()` to ensure that the users enter their old password and `matchingPasswords()` to ensure that the new password was re-typed correctly.

```
var $validate = array(
    // your existing validation rules
    'old_passwd' => array(
            'rule' => 'correctPassword',
            'message' => 'invalid password'
    ),
    'new_passwd' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 8),
            'message' => '8 characters minimum';
    ),
    'confirm_new_passwd' => array(
            'rule' => 'matchingPasswords',
            'message' => 'passwords do not match'
    )
);

function correctPassword($check) { }
function matchingPasswords($check) { }
```

See the Cookbook for more information about [custom validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules).

Comment: How should the correctPassword($check) method be defined? I mean, in order to check a password from the model, you need to specify the id of the user to look for. Since you cannot pass an id parameter in the validating rules, how can this be done?

Comment: If I recall correctly I had a hidden form element with the user's ID accessible via $this->data.

Comment: Oh, I mean yes, when you do the edit action, cake sets a hidden input with the id of the record you edit in order for the save() method to actually update a field, not add a new one. Forgot this one, thanks!